# Unable to run mule project in anypoint studio

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, mulesoft, mule4, anypoint-platform

I have a mule runtime 4.3.0 and anypoint studio 7.6.0. When I try to run a mule project I am getting the below error.

Error While Starting Mule

Exception Stack Trace:

```
     Java.lang.NullPointerException
At  org.mule.tooling.core.utils.VMUtils.getVMArguments(VMUtils.java:110).....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the project is corrupted. Try exporting it as a jar with sources and import it again under with project name.

Comment: Thanks!! It worked..Any reason why the project might have been corrupted.

Comment: The project might have been closed incorrectly, maybe studio crashed or the process was killed. Could be many things.